# I am trying to make an html/javascript audio player that plays audio according to scheduled time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an html/javascript audio player that plays audio according to time for example if its 1:00 pm the file starts playing from 0:00 minutes and if its 1:01 pm the file plays from 1:00 minutes

Comment: So what's your issue? Please show the code you have, the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it already. As currently written, it's impossible to tell what exactly are you asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you're looking for something like this:

```
<audio id="audio2"
   preload="auto"
   src="http://www.worldnationalanthem.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/National-Anthem-Of-The-United-States.mp3" >

   <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>

<script>
  var neededHours = 2; // use 24-hours format
  var currentdate = new Date();

  var h = currentdate.getHours(), m = currentdate.getMinutes(), s = currentdate.getSeconds();
  var passedTime = parseInt(m)*60+parseInt(s);

  myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
  myAudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    if(parseInt(h) == neededHours) {
        if(myAudio.duration > passedTime) {
            myAudio.currentTime = passedTime;
            myAudio.play();
        }
    }
  });
</script>
```

That's pretty easy example, but I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you I have very little experience at javascript and I am trying to finish a news website before November 30 so this was one of the major dilemmas I had and its solved

Comment: If possible mark the answer as complete, if you think it's good for you.